# Dynamic 3DObject use in ARKit-SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, collada

I want to download the 3D Object-dae(collada) file from server and want to display on surface dynamically so can please share how can I achieve this in ARKit via SceneKit or else?

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link: https://the-nerd.be/2014/11/07/dynamically-load-collada-files-in-scenekit-at-runtime/ it is old post but I don't think something is changed since that

According to this (see the Discussion section): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlasset/1391813-canimportfileextension?language=objc

dae is not supported at runtime (ModelIO).

Additionally I'm working on a library called [AssetKit](https://github.com/recp/assetkit) (In Progress) and it will full support COLLADA and glTF, it is too early to say that but after initial release, you will be able to load dae files dynamically. It is written with C99 but I'll optimize it for Swift (by writing wrappers or integration with SceneKit...). Since it is still in progress I suggest that follow the first link